Can the source code of Google Docs add-ons be seen or tampered with from the client?
I'm looking to develop a Google Docs add-on and am trying to think of security best practices. When installing a browser extension, it would obviously be downloaded entirely to the client (it can't be trusted), but what about a Google Docs add-on? If I have important/sensitive data that I need the add-on to process, is it okay to do it there directly or should I send the data to my server for processing like I would if it were an extension/website/mobile app?

It is OK to do your processing in Google Apps Script, as long as you sanitize and validate the inputs you get from the user interface.
Apps Script runs on Google's servers rather than in the web browser. Add-on source code cannot be seen by users, except for public function names. To make a function private and undiscoverable, add an underscore to the function's name, as in function myFunction_(){}. Alternatively, move those functions out of the global scope by encapsulating them in higher-level functions or classes.
Editor Add-on user interfaces are built with HTML/CSS/JavaScript, and run in the client. These user interfaces can be inspected and tinkered with by the user during runtime. Client-side code usually communicates with server-side code through the google.script interface.
Workspace Add-ons use a card-based model where the user interface is built using manifests and API calls. The result is rendered through HTML and friends by the client.

A Google Docs add-on uses the Google Apps Script platform as the server.
Google Apps Script projects are typically visible only to the project owner, editors, and viewers. Suppose the project was created using a Google Workspace account. In that case, the account administrators have the authority to transfer the project ownership to another account, thereby playing a crucial role in Apps Script project management.
If your Apps Script project creates dialogs and sidebars (using the HTML Service), the HtmlService.HtmlOutput content and the interactions between the web browser, the client, and the Google Apps Script platform, the server, can be seen by using web browser features like inspect code and built-in developer tools.
Please bear in mind that the names of top-level functions are sent to the client so they can be called from the client side using google.script.run. The exception is private function names (end with an underscore) —ref. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#private_functions. Other content in .gs, like code blocks and comments in .gs files, is unavailable to the client.
Properties from the Properties Service are unavailable on the client side unless explicitly exposed.
Logs created using Class Logger or console on the server side are not exposed to the client side unless they are explicitly inserted into the HtmlService.HtmlOutput content.
Related

Code security questions on Google Apps Script
Security of a GAS

